# Conjugacy classes of $A_7$

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

What I have got is the following as the representatives of the conjugacy classes:
$\mathrm{id}$, $(123)$, $(12345)$, $(12)(34)$, $(123)(456)$, $(1234)(56)$ which are the nonsplitting cases. The conjugacy class of $7$ cycles splits into two in $A_7$. So that gives me 8 conjugacy classes. But $A_7$ has 9. Which one am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing $(123)(45)(67)$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1914391)

Comment: @amWhy I am confused by your review.

Comment: Yes it does, @amWhy.

Comment: thanks for the answer!